# Elastic Search multi match query can't ignore special characters

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, graphql

I have a name field value as "abc_name" so when I search "abc_" I am getting proper results but when I search "abc_@#£&-#&" still I am getting same results. I want my query to ignore this special characters that doesn't matches with my query.

My query has:

- Multi_match
- type as cross_fields
- operator AND
- I am using search_analyzer standard for my Fields

And I want this structure as it is otherwise it will affect my other Search behaviour

```
  "name": {
         "type": "text",
           "fields": {
           "keyword": {
                 "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                     }
                       },
                     "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                 "search_analyzer": "standard"
                            }
```

Comment: what do you mean by **I want my query to ignore this special characters that doesn't matches with my query.**, do u want that the search result should be null when some other special characters (apart from that included in your field value) are included in the search query ?

Comment: Yes. I want empty results for this.

Comment: Can u please answer fast

Comment: I am working on your question only

Comment: Can u give me some inputs atleast

Answer (score 1):

Please see the below sample which would fit your use case where I've created a [custom analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html) which would fit your use case:

### Sample Mapping:

```
PUT some_test_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_custom_analyzer": { 
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "custom_tokenizer",
          "filter": ["lowercase", "3_5_edge_ngram"]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "custom_tokenizer": { 
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": "\\w+_+[^a-zA-Z\\d\\s_]+|\\s+".      <---- Note this pattern
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "3_5_edge_ngram": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 5
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "my_field":{
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_custom_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above mentioned pattern would simply ignore the tokens with the format like `abc_$%^^##`. As a result this token would not be indexed.

Note that the way the analyzer works is:

- First executes tokenizer
- Then applies the edge_ngram filter on the tokens generated.

You can verify by **simply removing the** `edge_ngram` ***filter*** in the above mapping to first understand what tokens are getting generated via [Analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) which would be as below:

```
POST some_test_index/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "my_custom_analyzer",
  "text": "abc_name asda efg_!@#!@# 1213_adav"
}
```

**Tokens generated:**

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "abc_name",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 8,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "asda",
      "start_offset" : 9,
      "end_offset" : 13,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "1213_adav",
      "start_offset" : 25,
      "end_offset" : 34,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that the token `efg_!@#!@#` has been removed.

I've added edge_ngram fitler as you would want the search to be successful if you search with `abc_` if your tokens generated via tokenizer is `abc_name`.

### Sample Document:

```
POST some_test_index/_doc/1
{
  "my_field": "abc_name asda efg_!@#!@# 1213_adav"
}
```

### Query Request:

**Use-case 1:**

```
POST some_test_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "my_field": "abc_"
    }
  }
}
```

**Use-case-2:**

```
POST some_test_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "my_field": "efg_!@#!@#"
    }
  }
}
```

### Responses:

**Response for use-case-1:**

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.47992462,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "some_test_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.47992462,
        "_source" : {
          "my_field" : "abc_name asda efg_!@#!@# 1213_adav"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Response for use-case-2:**

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

### Updated Answer:

Create your mapping as follows based on the index I've created and let me know if that works:

```
PUT some_test_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_custom_analyzer": { 
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "punctuation",
          "filter": ["lowercase"]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "punctuation": { 
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": "\\w+_+[^a-zA-Z\\d\\s_]+|\\s+"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "my_field":{
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "autocompete",                   <----- Assuming you have already this in setting
        "search_analyzer": "my_custom_analyzer".     <----- Note this
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please try and let me know if this works for all your use-cases.

Comment: But I am using analyzer autcomplete already so can i use 2 analyzers on any field.

Comment: hey @AbhijeetSanap Could you please update the question with your mapping. No you cannot use two analyzers on a field. You can make use of a different analyzer during searching i.e. via `search_analyzer` but no you cannot specify two analyzers on a field either during searching or indexing.

Comment: please check mapping i have updated above but I can't remove autocomplete.

Comment: I followed all the steps u mentioned above also I replaced analyzer autocomplete to my_custom_analyzer but still able to get that record with multiple special characters

Comment: @AbhijeetSanap I've updated answer but seeing your updated comment, well okay you are trying multiple things. First make only change in `search_analyzer` and see if that works with analyzer being `autocompete` that you have. If that doesn't work, please execute this and post the details in your question. `GET <your_index_name>/_settings`

Comment: I cant share mappings and settings here

Comment: shaall I replace my_custom_analyzer in setting with the one u gave in updated answer

Comment: ok I tried now and getting no results....remember I am using multimatch with cross fields

Comment: Could you first try creating new index as per what I've mentioned in answer and confirm if that is working. Second once that is done, could you create the same analyzer on your original index and then add that in `search_analyzer` instead of `standard` just for one field and see again if that is working. Just use simple match query. Now if that works, go ahead and add that to other fields and see now your use-case works. Now if that doesn't work could you share your settings so I can look into the `autocompete` analyzer that you have at your end.

Comment: http://localhost:9200/spec with this url and above body I am trying to create new index but getting erorrs on postman

Comment: Can u open ur chat box

Comment: @AbhijeetSanap Apologies. Could you let me know once you are online. I will open a chat and we can wrap this up.

Comment: @AbhijeetSanap Sorry I got caught up with work since last 2 days. Also I believe you do not have the min points required to be part of chat (need 20 points). Could you once try with the comment I've mentioned in the above steps and let me know what did you observe in each steps. I can probably break it down post that.